# Cheerio js unable to modify inner HTML

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm scraping a website using Cheerio js, I have a list of table lines in an array, when I modify the contents of the innner HTML using $.html('text') in a for loop seems to work but once the function exits I lose the modified text:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var bands = [];
var res = function (data) {
    for (var j=0; j < data.length; j++) {
        var perline = data[j];
        var $ = cheerio.load(perline);
        var chline = $('[class^="eventSlot"]');
        for (var i=0; i < chline.length; i++) {
            console.log($(chline[i]).html());   // looks correct
            $(chline[i]).html('some text');     // modify inner HTML
            console.log($(chline[i]).html());   // looks modified
        }
        bands.push(perline);
    }
    return bands;
};

var html = ['<td>11/04/2014</td><td><span class="eventSlot slot1 headliner">Band1</span><span class="eventSlot slot2">Band2</span></td><td>',
    '<td>11/04/2014</td><td><span class="eventSlot slot1 headliner">Band3</span></td>'];

console.log(res(html));  // contents are not modified from original html
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? If not, i'm working on it at work right now... i'll comment back if I figure it out. I want to say you use `replaceWith()` after you use Cheerio to export the html string with `$.html()`... but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to render to HTML each lines you are pushing to `bands` using Cheerio's `.html()` function. Your code would work if line 13 was changed to:

```
bands.push(perline.html());
```

Here is the full code:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var html = ['<td>11/04/2014</td><td><span class="eventSlot slot1 headliner">Band1</span><span class="eventSlot slot2">Band2</span></td><td>',
    '<td>11/04/2014</td><td><span class="eventSlot slot1 headliner">Band3</span></td>'];

var res = function (data) {
    for (var j=0; j < data.length; j++) {
        var perline = data[j];

        var $ = cheerio.load(perline);
        var chline = $('[class^="eventSlot"]');

        for (var i=0; i < chline.length; i++) {
            $(chline[i]).html('some text');     // modify inner HTML
        }
        bands.push(perline.html());     // Render the HTML back to text
    }
    return bands;
};

var bands = [];

console.log(res(html));  // contents *ARE* modified from original html
```

Something to consider: your approach seems a little odd in that you are converting HTML line by line. Maybe I'm missing what you indeed but I would think that you would operate on a larger block and then convert to HTML once at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `bands.push($.html())` as cheerio does not modify original source data. It modifies it's own DOM model. You have to call some cheerio rendering method to retrieve the modified model